# getting all the data from pivot table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model

i'm trying to get all the lead_id inside my pivot table but i can't make it work.

**controller:**

```
     $levels = Level::all();
     $levels->lead()->attach('lead_id');
     return $levels;
```

**Model Level:**

```
public function lead(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Lead::class, 'level_students')->withPivot('level_id', 'lead_id');
  }
```

**Model Lead:**

```
 public function level(){
return $this->belongsToMany(Level::class, 'level_students')->withPivot( 'lead_id', 'level_id');
```

}

Comment: Do you mean all the `lead_id` associated with a `Level` or ALL of the `lead_id` in the table?

Comment: all lead associated with level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean all `lead_id` of a `Level`, then you can use `pluck()`.

```
$level->lead->pluck('lead_id');
```

I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve because it seems that you want to retrieve all `lead_id` associated with any `Level`. But if that is the case, then you can create a model for the pivot table (e.g. `LevelLead`) and use `distinct()` or with Query Builder:

```
$leadIds = DB::table('level_students')->select('lead_id')->distinct()->get();
```

If you want to get the referenced table's column (e.g. `leads` table's `name` column) then you can use JOIN. Check [Laravel's doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins) for more options. For example, assuming the table name for `Lead` is `leads`, then:

```
$leads = DB::table('level_students')->join('leads', 'level_students.lead_id', '=', 'leads.lead_id')->select('level_students.lead_id', 'leads.name')->distinct()->get();
```

Comment: sir how do i retrieve all lead_id associated with any Level.

Comment: sir follow up question, how can i replace the id to names in blade?

Comment: @Grace names? do you mean `Lead`'s name?

Comment: @Grace updated my answer. Now you can retrieve the name